# Localtunnel running problem, doesn't work at all

Tags: localtunnel

I installed localtunnel globaly by runnnig this command `npm install -g localtunnel`.

After that when I run `lt --port 8080`, absolutely nothing happens. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Use a Cloudflare tunnel instead: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/run-tunnel/trycloudflare/

Answer (score 20):

It appears that the author isn't maintaining Local Tunnel much these days, but there was a helpful [comment](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/343#issuecomment-588489442) on the github issue dealing with this.  At the time of writing this, you can generate a Local Tunnel with

```
lt -h "http://serverless.social" -p 8080
```

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
lt -p 8080 -h http://localtunnel.me
```

And in the URL you get, replace the "https" with "http". Maybe don't open it with Google Chrome but with Safari instead, but Google Chrome might work, too.

For more information see: https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/332

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue on my raspberry pi. You need to validate your `npm` and `localtunnel` installation. Check if you get valid results for `npm --version`. If not, reinstalling `npm` will fix the problem. In case you installed `localtunnel` locally (instead of the -g option), you may have to use the command like:
`npx localtunnel --port <port>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like localtunnel is currently down.
Click [here](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/343) to go to the github issues page for more information and updates

Comment: Of course you could use ngrok.io instead of localtunnel, the only difference between the two is that ngrok.io doesn't support custom subdomains in their free plan.

Answer (score 1):

run this

```
lt -h "https://serverless.social" -p 8080
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple thing though insecure to host it:

```
lt --port 443 -h "http://localtunnel.me" -s myhost
```

and then in another tab:

```
python3 -m http.server 443
```

This worked for me.
The consequence was that the device on which I was accessing my site showed complete root directory(I am sure there are configurations to be made to prevent this)

Answer (score 0):

change the port from 8080 to 8000 the issue might be because of on port 8080 there is something already running .

Answer (score 0):

LocalTunnel is refusing to connect when using node 18. I've downgraded to 16 and it's working fine. I don't know the reason, but it seems to be IPv6 related.

If you're having trouble with it, try running with `DEBUG`:

```bash
export DEBUG="localtunnel:*" && lt --port 8080
```

For reference, this is the error I seen when using node 18 with the `DEBUG` flag:

```bash
localtunnel:client local error connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3939 +0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

After "npm install -g localtunnel" try this:

```
C:\> npx lt -p 8080 -s myserver --print-requests
your url is: https://myserver.loca.lt
```

Or without -s param to get a random URL.